# How to filter a vector, but get indices instead of values?

Tags: vector, filter, rust

I know how to filter a vector and get the *values* that match that filter:

```rust
let vec: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12];
let filtered: Vec<u32> = v.into_iter().filter(|x| x % 3 == 0).collect();
println!("{:?}", filtered);
// [3, 9, 12]
```

But how do I get the *index* of the values that match that filter?

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to use `enumerate` and `filter_map`:

```rust
let v: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12];
let filtered: Vec<usize> = v.iter()
    .enumerate()
    .filter_map(|(i,x)| (x % 3 == 0).then(|| i))
    .collect();
println!("{:?}", filtered);
// [1, 4, 6]
```

---

### However...

If your goal is to use these indices to access a *different* vector of the same size, you may be better off with `zip`:

```
let vect: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12];
let other_vect: Vec<u32> = vec![9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3];

// Filtering `other_vect` from filter on `vect`
let other_filtered: Vec<&u32> = vect.iter().zip(other_vect.iter())
    .filter_map(|x| (x.0 % 3 == 0).then(|| x.1))
    .collect();

println!("{:?}", other_filtered); //[8, 5, 3]
```

Comment: Probably not super useful, if the `vec` is consumed in the process ... maybe `iter()` instead? Although I don't know OP's usecase, of course

Comment: @Finomnis My usecase was to actually index it in a _different_ vector of the same size, so I was fine with that. But in hindsight, yeah, there's no reason to use `into_iter`. Just edited it out.

Comment: The `if` can be replaced with `(x % 3 == 0).then(|| i)` (and in a future version of Rust, with `(x % 3 == 0).then_some(i)`.